# what is wrong when oil leaks from bottom of oil pan in a 1992 toyota corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, oil-leak

I have a 1992 Toyota Corolla. There is oil streaming from the bottom of the

OIL PAN-there is a round rubber plug there and oil is coming out of it.

Comment: A round rubber plug? Can you take a picture of it?

Comment: Are you sure it's rubber?  It may be the sump plug (which is usually metal with a copper seal).  If it's the sump plug, they are available from the dealer for a very small fee.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a rubber plug in an oil pan. If there really is, then you either need a new oil pan (if the plug isn't the drain plug) or a new drain plug. A new drain plug should be available from a dealer or an auto parts store and can easily be replaced. If your oil pan has been damaged and someone repaired it with a rubber plug then you will likely need to have the oil pan replaced, which will be more costly.

Are you sure the plug is rubber? Oil drain plugs frequently pick up a black patina due to oil and road dust and may appear to be rubber. If the plug isn't rubber and is simply leaking, then you should be able to tighten it yourself with a wrench. It may be worth taking it to a shop the verify that the plug has a proper copper sealing gasket installed.